# comparing an inputted string to a printed function

Tags: c, visual-studio

Below is a code I wrote for a dice game called cho han. To input your guess I've used number to represent the words 'odd' and 'even'. Since then I have tried to write it again, but to actually write odd or even in the scanf section, but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
//cho-han

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
srand(time(NULL));

int x = (rand() % 6) + 1;
int y = (rand() % 6) + 1;
int result = 0;
int guess = 0;

printf("The values of two dice rolls will be added up. The aim is to guess whether that total number will be odd or even.\n");
printf("To guess odd, enter '1'. To guess even, enter '2'.\n\n");
printf("Please enter your guess for the combined total of the two dice rolls: ");

scanf_s("%d", &guess);
if (guess == 2)
{
    printf("\nyour guess is even.\n");
}
if (guess == 1)
{
    printf("\nyour guess is odd.\n");
}
if (guess > 2 || guess < 1)
{
    printf("\nInvalid guess.\nYou lose!\n");
    return (1);
}

printf("\ndice roll 1 = %d\n", x);
printf("dice roll 2 = %d\n", y);

result = x + y;
printf("\ncombined total of both rolls is %d", result);

if (result == 1 || result == 3 || result == 5 || result == 7 || result == 9 || result == 11)
{
    printf("\ncombined total of both rolls is odd.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\ncombined total of both rolls is even.\n");

}

if (guess == 1 && result == 1 || guess == 1 && result == 3 || guess == 1 && result == 5 || guess == 1 && result == 7 || guess == 1 && result == 9 || guess == 1 && result == 11)
{
    printf("\nYou win!\n");
}
else if (guess == 2 && result == 2 || guess == 2 && result == 4 || guess == 2 && result == 6 || guess == 2 && result == 8 || guess == 2 && result == 10 || guess == 2 && result == 12)
{ 
    printf("\nYou win!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nYou lose!\n");
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: scan a string and use `strcmp`.

Comment: To make it a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you could probably delete everything after the part with the `scanf` from your question. Adding code that is not related to the question is only distraction people.

Comment: Your code only shows the initial version with numbers. Please show us your effort where you try to read the words. Then we can see where you are stuck and what you need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should change `scanf_s` to `scanf`
2. The line `if (result == 1 || result == 3 ...` could be `if (result % 2 == 1) {`
3. You could use `strcmp` to solve your question

The following `code` could work:

```
   //cho-han

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int x = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int y = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int result = 0;
    int guess = 0;
    char buf[10];

    printf("The values of two dice rolls will be added up. The aim is to guess whether that total number will be odd or even.\n");
    printf("To guess odd, enter 'odd'. To guess even, enter 'even'.\n\n");
    printf("Please enter your guess for the combined total of the two dice rolls: ");

    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    if (strcmp(buf, "even\n") == 0) {
        guess = 2;
        printf("\nyour guess is even.\n");
    } else if (strcmp(buf, "odd\n") == 0) {
        guess = 1;
        printf("\nyour guess is odd.\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nInvalid guess.\nYou lose!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\ndice roll 1 = %d\n", x);
    printf("dice roll 2 = %d\n", y);
    printf("\ncombined total of both rolls is %d", x + y);

    result = (x + y) % 2;
    if (result == 1)
        printf("\ncombined total of both rolls is odd.\n");
    else
        printf("\ncombined total of both rolls is even.\n");

    if (guess == result)
        printf("\nYou win!\n");
    else
        printf("\nYou lose!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `if (result % 2 == 1) {` is OK when `result >= 0`, as in this case, yet `result % 2 == 1` is an incorrect test for odd-ness when `result < 0`.  I'd recommend  `if (result % 2) {` or its equivalent `if (result % 2 != 0) {`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your guess to char type and scanf to capture string.

```
char guess[256];
scanf("%s", guess);
```

And then the best way would be to call toupper() and compare with your text using strcmp().